# Parameter validation failed: BOTO3 DynamoDB PutItem

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following code, which gets a list of json from s3. Then that json I want to store in my dynamo database, I am adding the types but for TYPE 'L' which has a list of objects it throws an error

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
client = session.resource('s3')
bucket = client.Bucket('test-bucket')

def getFile():
    for object_summary in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="dev/companies/data/"):
        body = object_summary.get()['Body'].read()
    return body

def representatives(representatives):
   listOfDicts = []
   for representative in representatives:
       temp = {
       'person': { 'S' :  representative['person']},
       'type_number_doc': { 'S' : representative['type_number_doc']},
       'charge': { 'S' : representative['charge']},
       'date_start_charge': { 'S' : representative['date_start_charge']}
       }
    listOfDicts.append(temp)
return listOfDicts
   
item =  {
    "representatives"  :{'L': representatives(dictItems['representatives'])},
    }

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb.put_item(TableName='equifax', Item=item)
```

the error

> Unknown parameter in Item.representatives.L[0]: "person", must be one
> of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in
> Item.representatives.L[0]: "type_number_doc", must be one of: S, N, B,
> SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in
> Item.representatives.L[0]: "charge", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS,
> BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in Item.representatives.L[0]:
> "date_start_charge", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL,
> BOOL Unknown parameter in Item.representatives.L[1]: "person", must be
> one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in
> Item.representatives.L[1]: "type_number_doc", must be one of: S, N, B,
> SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in
> Item.representatives.L[1]: "charge", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS,
> BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL Unknown parameter in Item.representatives.L[1]:
> "date_start_charge", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL,
> BOOL

Comment: Unrelated, I don't see any potential key attribute(s) in your item. You can't put an item without key attributes.

Comment: I'd also recommend using the resource-level API (rather than the client-level API) via `table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table('equifax')`, then you can use native Python types such as lists in your items and you don't have to indicate attribute types such as "S", "N", "L" etc.